# Using TIPA with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, tipa

I'm trying to write a document that will contain characters in many different scripts (for which I am using fontspec and rendering with xelatex) and IPA symbols (for which I am using TIPA). Ordinarily, this works fine, however, I want to use slshape for my IPA symbols. If I take the manual's advice and use

```
\textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}
```

Or

```
\textipa{\textsl{f@"nEtIks}}
```

It fails with fontspec loaded. The document renders properly, but the IPA symbols appear upright. If I remove fontspec, then this works correctly, with the IPA symbols slanted. I tried getting fontspec to use tipasl12, but I could not find a way of allowing fontspec to use the font. However I named it, fontspec could not find the font.

This is the LaTeX I have which produces the correct IPA symbols, but they appear upright:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

  \textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}

\end{document}
```

The following, however, works perfectly, but - obviously - would not allow me to use Arabic characters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
%\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

  \textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Arabic font is not a factor. The problem is that `fontspec` redefines `\textipa` under the assumption that the Latin Modern fonts have the IPA glyphs, which however should be called by Unicode.

Solution: restore the Computer Modern fonts for IPA.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\textipa[1]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\tipaencoding #1}}

  \textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}

\end{document}
```

---

A more complete version, taking into account also the need for typewriter type:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\textipa[2][r]{{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding #2}}
}

\renewenvironment{IPA}[1][r]
 {\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding}
 {}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}

\textipa[tt]{f@"nEtIks}

\begin{IPA}f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}

\begin{IPA}[tt]f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}

\begin{IPA}\slshape f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, egreg, thanks very much that works perfectly :) Sadly, however, I have to ask you to extend a little more help. That worked really nicely, but using \textipa{} with fontspec, for some reason, causes the symbols ", E and I not to display. They do display correctly within the IPA environment, i.e. between \begin{IPA}\end{IPA}. Using \begin{IPA}\slshape f@"nEtIks\end{IPA} does work (although \begin{IPA}\textsl{f@"nEtIks}\end{IPA} seems not to. Obviously that doesn't matter much, but I wanted to try typewriter text and, sadly, neither \ttfamily nor \texttt{} seem to work.

Comment: N.B.: I had to include a slight modification of your original advice:
\renewenvironment{IPA}{\fontfamily{cmr}\tipaencoding}{}
in order to get the IPA environment to work with \slshape

Comment: It's strange, because with the suggested redefinition of `\textipa`, the `IPA` environment gives correct results to me.

Comment: Hmmmmm I thought that, perhaps because, by using \ttfamily I am declaring a new font family - does computer modern (as in cmr) include computer modern's typewriter text font. I'm not actually sure whether the default is teletype, teletype l or typewriter proportional.

Comment: @user16968 The problem is indeed in the typewriter type family; if you plan to use TIPA characters in typewriter type, then you have to stick to Computer Modern.

Comment: Hmmmm, okay, thank you. So, with the definition of the IPA environment and \textipa{} above:
\textipa{\texttt{f@"nEtIks}}
produces fǝ n t ks in the default monospace font, whilst:
\begin{IPA}\texttt{f@"nEtIks}}\end{IPA}
produces fǝˈnɛtɪks with the standard, computer modern font. What should I be using instead?

Comment: Oho, that is very good - well done and thanks very much :) :)

Comment: For people who want sans serif text: just use the above code with `\textipa[ss]{...}`.