# loading fontenc breaks tipa

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, tipa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using TIPA with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec)

I try to get an a with a dash and a glotal stop typeset. Depending on the ordering of the loading of the packages I get either the ā or the ʔ. Do I have to choose or is there a way to fix this? I also tried to type it directly, but did not see anything in the output ...

```
\documentclass[T1]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{fontspec}



\begin{document}

pazirā\textglotstop i


\end{document}
```

I also looked at [Using TIPA with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec) but this does not seem to help here ...

Comment: If you're using `fontspec` you're using `xelatex` or `lualatex` in which case you generally shouldn't be using the `[T1]` option of `scrbook`.  If you use a proper Unicode phonetic font (like SIL Doulos) you can input the IPA directly without using TIPA at all.  See [Using TeX for writing papers on linguistics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542/2693).

Comment: Remove the `T1` option. The input `pazirā{\tipaencoding\textglotstop}i` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `fontspec` you're using `xelatex` or `lualatex` in which case you generally shouldn't be using the `[T1]` option of `scrbook`. If you use a proper Unicode phonetic font (like SIL Doulos) you can input the IPA directly without using TIPA at all. See [How to use phonetic IPA characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542/2693).