# tipa with fontspec redux: tilde above characters

Tags: fontspec, tipa

I'm trying to use the `tipa` package with `fontspec`, but they don't play nice together. I've read previous questions trying to solve the issues that come up (like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec)), and that's the solution I've been using so far.

However, I've bumped into a problem that I can't really understand. Below I include a (unrealistically brief) MWE taken from the question linked to above. The real document is much more complex, but this illustrates the problem nicely. The following document compiles with no warnings or errors for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\textipa[2][r]{{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding #2}}
}
\renewenvironment{IPA}[1][r]
{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding}
{}

\begin{document}
  \textipa{f@"nEtIks}
\end{document}
```

But adding a line like

```
\textipa{\~an\~a}
```

breaks it. What is really puzzling is that compilation halts without any sort of warning, even with `-interaction=nonstopmode` enabled. In the above example I could simply use `\~an\~a`, without the `tipa` environment, but in other cases this is not an option.

I've read the [recommendations for linguistics papers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/using-tex-for-writing-papers-on-linguistics), but since all my transcriptions are already typed out using `tipa`, I'm reluctant to give it up and start doing the charmap spelunking that would be necessary.

Is there a way to use `\~` in a `tipa` environment while still using `fontspec`?

Comment: Just remove the `fontspec` line and it will work.

Comment: It also works if I don't use `\~`, but that's the whole point: I _need_ `fontspec` just as much as I _need_ `\~`. I find it hard to believe that it is not possible to use both.

Comment: Tex doesn't stop, adding `\tracingall` shows that `\~` gets itself into an infinite loop expanding to a definition that includes itself. Not entirely sure why yet

Comment: `{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\~ a}` works although it's a bit less than ideal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that does work, but it doesn't seem to keep the `tipa` environment, does it? Because something like `\textipa{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\~ O}na}` does not print a nasalised ɔ but an O with a tilde on top.

Comment: @jja Yes I know, It was late and I was just making comments as I spotted things, sorry no answer to post yet, fontspec changes a lot of things and I don't know it well....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is `xunicode`, which as observed in the linked question makes some changes to the `tipa` system on the assumption that Latin Modern has appropriate glyph coverage. Perhaps the easiest way around this is to prevent `xunicode` loading at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@xunicode.sty\endcsname{}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
  \textipa{\~O}
\end{document}
```

as the `tipa` mechanism is then left alone. Note that this may break other things: the outcome will very much depend on the real documents involved. (You may need to manually 'restore' parts of `xunicode`.)

Comment: It's been some time since I asked this question, so I can't even remember what the eventual solution I used was. But this definitely solves the issue at hand, so I'm going to accept this. And damn the consequences of those things that might get broken! :)