# drawing vertical lines on top of symbols

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, tipa

I need to add a vertical bar above and below a few letters. I'm using the tipa package, and it works as long as that's the only package I load. I also need to load polyglossia to type a few foreign characters. But when I do, I lose the functionality from tipa (the vertical bars no longer appear). Here's a minimal example that works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\textvbaraccent{S}
\textsyllabic{S}
\end{document}
```

Here's an example that fails to produce the vertical bars

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
\textvbaraccent{S}
\textsyllabic{S}
\end{document}
```

If I load polyglossia before tipa, then I get the following error message: '! LaTeX Error: Command \sups already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.'

I'm running Texmaker on windows 8, using XelaTex

Edit:
I also tried restoring the computer modern fonts for IPA as suggested in this post [Using TIPA with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `tipa` has issues with `fontspec`, not `polyglossia`. Joseph Wright's [answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127427/24974) should make things right.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the link. It solved the problem :)