# tipa doesn't make all tildes

Tags: tilde, tipa

I am using the `tipa` package to write some phonetic things, and it doesn't work well with the tilde for some characters :

`\~a` or `\~e` do work well, but not `\~\textscripta`, `\~\textopeno`, `\~\textepsilon`, or `\~\oe` (or not so well for the last one)

I've also tried with `$\tilde{\textscripta}$`, `$\tilde{\textopeno}$`, `{$\tilde{\textepsilon}$`, `$\tilde{\oe}$`, but the result is also bad.

What I want to show can be seen on the very bottom of this page :
http://www.sfu.ca/fren270/Phonetique/trapeze.html

I will be able to show a MWE or some images if needed.

I am not using fontspec so the question is not the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100059/tipa-with-fontspec-redux-tilde-above-characters)

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Can you make a small minimal (non) working example?

Answer (score 1):

After having read further the manual, here's the answer : I have to put them in an `\textipa` environment :

```
\textipa{\~A}, \textipa{\~O}, \textipa{\~E}, \textipa{\~\oe}
```

do work well

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

This is what I got with **version 1.3** in the simple code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\~a, \~e, \~\textscripta, \~\textopeno, \~\textepsilon, or \~\oe
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @sigur , I don't know why it wasn't working, because now your code also works. Maybe because I had created my own command : `\newcommand{\phonet}[1]{\texttt{[#1]}}`, and the code was inside. Now I have done `\newcommand{\phonet}[1]{\textipa{\texttt{[#1]}}}` and everything works fine. Anyway, I have discovered the `\textipa` envrionment, which I think is always better than the `\text…` commands (there are small visible differences, particularly for the tilde).