# XeLaTeX and `tipa`

Tags: xetex, tipa

So, this code works with `XeLaTeX`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\textipa[2][r]{{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding #2}}
}

\renewenvironment{IPA}[1][r]
 {\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding}
 {}

\begin{document}
%\textipa{\slshape pUK.t\~A}
\textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}

\textipa[tt]{f@"nEtIks}

\begin{IPA}f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}

\begin{IPA}[tt]f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}

\begin{IPA}\slshape f@"nEtIks\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

But when I uncomment the line 
`%\textipa{\slshape pUK.t\~A}`
just after the `\begin{document}`, it no longer compiles. How should I correct it?

Comment: I don't know anything about this can `\~A` be replaced by `Ã`? It certainly compiles but whether it compiles to the correct thing, I know not!

Comment: To the editor: deleting all blank lines is not helpful. Within the text body, blank lines are ***part of the code and have semantic meaning***. Deleting them ***changes the typeset output***.  Within the preamble, they are often used to make code more readable. Removing these wholesale does not, in my opinion, improve the question and I have reverted most of these changes. (I've reduced multiple blank lines to 1 and removed a spurious space, but the rest is part of the MWE in my view.)

Comment: @Romain Picot ^^

Comment: @cfr, no, it should give `puʁ.tɑ̃`, as in https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourtant (the pronunciation of `pourtant`).

Comment: I know what it would give because it works with `latex` (often inside math environment).

Comment: If you are already using XeLaTeX it makes more sense to not use TIPA but instead just define a new font family that contains phonetic characters and enter them directly into your source.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224164/2693 for more comments.

Comment: Also, how isn't this duplicate of [Using TIPA with fontspec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64830/2693)?

Comment: @AlanMunn, indeed, I copied the code from there but the problem is entirely different. I try to adapt it for my purpose...

Comment: The issue is the same as in the duplicate question; besides, the current version of `fontspec` makes the code compile as is.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more of a suggestion for an alternative, and I think easier, method. Since you're using Xelatex already, you can set a regular font for your text, and a font only for IPA, therefore inputing IPA directly in your editor. I think it's also more readable when editing than `tipa`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Century Gothic}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Charis SIL}
\newcommand\ipa[1]{{\ipafont #1}}

\begin{document}\noindent
This is a paper about Linguistics (IPA: \ipa{lɪŋgwɪstɪks}). And it goes on...
\end{document}
```

I've set the regular font to something different than the default font, something more noticeable, so you see the difference.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

Here I finally found the answer, after 24hrs of searching and trying. I hope this solves everything, although I may obtain new errors with increasing size of the document.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127427/80224

Comment: An answer that just provides a link to another answer is not an answer.