# TIPA package causing error in xelatex: \sups already defined

Tags: xetex, tipa, bibentry

I am trying to include some of my publications in my CV, which it typeset in LaTeX. I have a .bib file and I call the references using \bibverse{}. The problem is that I am unable to compile the document, and I believe this is happening because some of the articles have IPA symbols in the title. I get the following error:

```
Argument of \BR@@lbibitem has an extra }. [   \bibverse{article2012}]
```

The bib items do not have extra }'s. My initial guess was that the IPA symbols in the title were causing the problem, so I included the TIPA package, and got the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \sups already defined. [  \lower.8ex\hbox{\super{#2}}}{#1}}}]
```

I am unclear on what \sups are and google searching has not been of any help. I am aware that TIPA should not be necessary when using XeLaTex. One possibility would be to not use TIPA in my .bib file, but the problem is that I use this file in many documents that are not compiled in xelatex so I prefer to keep it constant.

This is what my preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\newcommand{\bibverse}[1]{\begin{verse} \bibentry{#1}. \end{verse}}

\begin{document}

\textteshlig
\bibverse{publication1}

\nobibliography*
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nobibliography{publicationsCV}
\end{document}
```

Edit: The reason I tried to compile the document using TIPA is because the .bib file includes ipa characters (i.e. \textteshlig). The reason for using the verse environment is to be able to insert full references (my publications) where need be. For example, my cv has a section for conference presentations. If I were to simply generate a bibliography I would have no control over what goes where. Here is an example of what the bib verse looks like in the .tex file.

```
\bibverse{publication1}
```

And here is an example of what it looks like in the .bib file.

```
@conference{publication1,
Author = {My Name},
Month = {April},
Organization = {In Selected Proceedings of the a Conference.},
Place = {University of Somewhere, City, State},
Publisher = {Some publisher},
Title = {Title with IPA symbols: /\textteshlig/},
Year = {2013}}
```

This works fine in other documents compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: What's the purpose of loading `tipa`? Can you add one of the entries where you'd need it? And what's the purpose of calling `\bibentry` in a `verse` environment?

Comment: I get no output from your example; however, you solve the immediate issue by adding `\let\sups\relax` just before `\usepackage{tipa}`. However, this is *not* the correct way of doing: use the Unicode character instead of `\texteshlig` (and a font that has it).

Comment: Ok. I guess I can have to separate .bib files, one with IPA in unicode and one with TIPA. If I do this I still have a problem with the compiling the bib references. The error is the same as I pointed out above: `./file.tex:261: Argument of \BR@@lbibitem has an extra }. [   \bibverse{article1}]`. Again, there isn't an extra "}", and this method words in pdflatex. Any idea what might be happening? Or do you know of another way to include full references without generating an entire bibliography?

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted (with TIPA) by using the hyperref package. I did not have to change any of the fonts. I simply piggy backed the solution given [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec), which also provided by you (egreg). If you provide an answer I will accept it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's probably better to close as duplicate, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be appropriate.