# Looking for a package/method that can make "best-guess" (heuristic) accents onto a font that doesn't have latin-extended support

Tags: fonts, xetex, packages, fontspec, extended-characters

I have a lot of printed content using a particular font, and I'm trying to extend localisation with latin-extended-a charsets, but the font I'm using doesn't support it (It's a TTF - using fontspec and XeLaTeX).

Of course finding a similar font is a backup option, but I wonder if it's possible to make TeX draw accents onto a font using some heuristic or best-fit guess?

Something like `H\={e}llo` but for fonts that don't have ē - so maybe `H\fit={e}llo`-like command is available?

Cheers,

Comment: Is perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294998/fonts-with-well-behaved-stacking-diacritics a related question?

Comment: @bluebirch thanks for the reference - I've accepted the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I define `\fit` as suggested by the OP, it may prove easier to then incorporate `\fit` into macros tailored for the accent (shown for `\macron` and `\umlaut`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\fit[3][.3ex]{\stackengine{#1}{#3}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\newcommand\macron[1]{\fit{\kern-.2ex\_}{#1}}
\newcommand\umlaut[1]{\fit{\kern-.05ex.\kern-.15ex.}{#1}}
%\let\=\macron
%\let\"\umlaut
\begin{document}
H\=ello  H\macron ello
\"Apfel \umlaut Apfel

\Huge
H\=ello  H\macron ello\par
\"Apfel \umlaut Apfel
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you truly have no need for the original definitions (because they don't work in your font), you could redefine the originals with these preamble declarations:

```
\let\=\macron
\let\"\umlaut
```

Comment: I used  this method and it worked pretty well - only took about an hour to make all the accents I needed for this particular font. This isn't really an "automatic" best guess, but the result is really nice. Thanks!

Comment: @Blake Thanks.  If you need under-accents, like a `\c` cedilla, for example, I would add an extra macro, `\newcommand\ufit[3][0ex]{\stackengine{#1}{#3}{#2}{U}{c}{F}{T}{S}}` which stacks under, rather than over, the argument.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. Since the font is script, I actually made a few fits and underfits - fit, fitb, fitc, ufit, ufitb, to line up with all the examples. Then some nice macros for each like \ncedilla etc. Cheers!

Comment: in lualatex this not working: avail lists: 1:2,2:39,3:4,4:1,5:20,6:57,7:62,8:1,9:26
! error:  (type 0): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @MarkoLustro I just tried it with lualatex and it works fine for me.  Make sure `stackengine` package is up to date (2017/02/13 v4.01).