# How to get E as small capital with macron with Libertinus font? (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, fontspec

The following MWE doesn’t show a small capital of `Ē` ([http://graphemica.com/Ē](http://graphemica.com/%C4%92))[image]

Is there no such letter with the font `libertinus` or how can I make it happen with `LuaLaTeX`?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[%
  Numbers     = {Monospaced, OldStyle},
  Scale       = 0.95,
]{Libertinus Sans}
\setmainfont[%
  Numbers     = {Monospaced, OldStyle},
  Scale       = 0.95,
]{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
ēĒasdfjklö\textsc{asdfēĒjklö}asdfjklöēĒ

\sffamily
ēĒasdfjklö\textsc{asdfēĒjklö}asdfjklöēĒ
\end{document}
```

---

The workaround with

`\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\fit[3][.3ex]{\stackengine{#1}{#3}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\newcommand\macron[1]{\fit{\kern-.2ex\_}{#1}}
\newcommand\umlaut[1]{\fit{\kern-.05ex.\kern-.15ex.}{#1}}`

works semi-well, since the bar is too long then. [image]

Comment: Does `\textsc{\=e}` work?

Comment: nope. same result as putting in the character directly.

Comment: Then maybe this question could help, on how to fudge accents for fonts that don't have them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390388/looking-for-a-package-method-that-can-make-best-guess-heuristic-accents-onto

Comment: Apparently, the font has no small caps variant for the “e with macron”.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes see my updated question.

Comment: How about `\newcommand\scmacron[1]{\fit[.2ex]{\tiny\_}{#1}}`?  Here, I chose `\tiny`, but you could pick the best size.

Comment: There is a combining macron (U+0304) in the font and e.sc without a unicode slot. So entering `\textsc{ē}` (regular e and then U+0304 however your system allows you to input this) should work. You might want to kern it a tiny bit (eg. `\textsc{e\kern-.03em̄}`and/or to define a shorthand for it.

Comment: If you cannot/don't want to input the chars directly, you could adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120762/6819 and call the glyphs by name and/or slot. XeLaTeX comes with the `\char{}`-command built-in.

Comment: I just see that `\char` obviously *is* available in LuaLaTeX for Unicode slots, so `\textsc{e\kern-.03em\char"0304}` should work just fine

Comment: @Florian your solution is easy to apply and works fine! I take it.