# "Umlaut" works -- except for Ü

Tags: german

for some reason some of my Umlauts work, others not.

For your fun, see here:

[image: Umlaut-test]

The capital Ä turns weird, and the capital Ü does not get displayed at all. The rest looks just fine.

I am confused.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter} % Specify the font size (10pt, 11pt and 12pt) and paper size (letterpaper, a4paper, etc)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{microtype} % Improves typography
\usepackage{gfsdidot} % Use the GFS Didot font: 
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsdidot/
\usepackage{miama}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
{Address}
\opening{
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
blah blah
a Ä ä\\
o Ö ö\\
u Ü ü\\
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen \LARGE \fmmfamily  }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Maybe some of the packages collide with each other?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Your MWE does not include any Ä or Ü...

Comment: Ha, great beginner's mistake! I will add it right away...

Comment: If the font is missing the glyph, you might fudge it with this approach, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390388/looking-for-a-package-method-that-can-make-best-guess-heuristic-accents-onto

Comment: @PikkuKatja related discussion: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-02/msg00266.html I suggest to use another font

Comment: Cool, thank you! I guess, so far I have never used the capital versions in one of my letters, so I did not notice. I guess it is indeed the best to use another font. Do you want to write this up as answer?

Comment: Gfs Didot does have a capital U with umlaut. Whether it is usable with LaTeX is another problem. Unrelated: the `hyperref` package should be loaded as the last package, with very few  exceptions (most notable `cleveref`).

Comment: `Address` is not German ;-) It's `Adresse`

Comment: If only there was some... widely available... unified standard... for encoding characters across many character sets.

Comment: thank you, Bernard, for the hint -- I will do that in future.
and yes, Christian, this is what happens when you take the actual letter, delete all content to create a MWE and then add something back in when writing the question in English. Luckily, it did not distract this wonderful community to help me with the problem. :) I sent the letter yesterday, and trust me, the address was in German. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As several have noted, the font has problems.  Not only the missing umlauted characters, but also a capital U with zero apparent height.

If the use of the font is necessary, I suggest fudging the umlauts using a tailored version of `\umlaut`, originally provided in [Looking for a package/method that can make "best-guess" (heuristic) accents onto a font that doesn't have latin-extended support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390388/looking-for-a-package-method-that-can-make-best-guess-heuristic-accents-onto).

Normally, `\umlaut U` would be sufficient, but because of the bad height of the `U`, `\umlaut{U\vphantom{A}}` is required in this case.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter} % Specify the font size (10pt, 11pt and 12pt) and paper size (letterpaper, a4paper, etc)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{microtype} % Improves typography
\usepackage{gfsdidot} % Use the GFS Didot font: 
%http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsdidot/
\usepackage{miama}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\fit[3][.3ex]{\stackengine{#1}{#3}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\newcommand\umlaut[1]{\fit[.05ex]{\scriptsize..}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
{Address}
\opening{
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
blah blah\\
a \umlaut A ä\\
o Ö ö\\
u \umlaut{U\vphantom{A}} ü\\
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen \LARGE \fmmfamily  }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If compiling with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX is an option, consider using the OpenType font (packaged with [`gfsdidot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gfsdidot) as well) instead of the Type 1 font which appears to be buggy:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{miama}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
{Address}
\opening{
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
blah blah
a Ä ä\\
o Ö ö\\
u Ü ü\\
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen \LARGE \fmmfamily  }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled example document with correct umlauts]

Comment: Thank you, diabonas -- I have not worked with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX yet; our company works with pdfLaTeX normally. If that changes at some point, I might come back to your solution :-)