# How to create my own diacritic (caron etc.)?

Tags: fonts, luatex

I need my own character and I need to use it in LaTeX.

In LaTeX we have `\={a}` `\.{a}` etc.

How can I can create my own character? For example I have two glyphs, my version of tilde `~` and char `a`.

How to define a new character \~{a} with the specific character and tilde? Or how to add two tildes above 'e'?

Maybe creating a virtual font is the simplest way?

Comment: The macro `\~` is already defined.  I would choose a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer at [Looking for a package/method that can make "best-guess" (heuristic) accents onto a font that doesn't have latin-extended support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390388/looking-for-a-package-method-that-can-make-best-guess-heuristic-accents-onto)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\fit[3][0ex]{\stackengine{#1}{#3}{\smash{#2}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\newcommand\mytilde[2][-1.2ex]{\fit[#1]{\~{}}{#2}}
\newcommand\myring[2][-1.2ex]{\fit[#1]{\r{}}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\mytilde A\mytilde a
\mytilde[-4.3pt]{\mytilde e}
\mytilde[-11.5pt]{\mytilde e}

\myring A\myring a
\myring[-3.3pt]{\myring e}
\myring[-11.5pt]{\myring e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `e̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "To infinity...and beyond!!!"

Comment: can you show me answer without {stackengine}? simple as possible answer.  i need different char above letter. Not only doule ~ or one ~ sometimes i need one 'o' and ~ above and dot left 'o'

Comment: @MarkoLustro I have to leave momentarily, but suggest you look into the `\ooalign` primitive and `\raisebox` to accomplish similar things.  By the way, `stackengine` can align to the left, center, or right, and by adding blank space on one side of the stacked item, it will shift that item to the left or right, accordingly.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes can You write example? a with 2 cediles, a with 4 dot above. How defining it correctly.

Comment: i read this example and get : avail lists: 1:2,2:39,3:4,4:1,5:20,6:57,7:62,8:1,9:26
! error:  (type 0): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!