# Stacked diacritics list

Tags: unicode, accents, linguistics, tipa, phonetic

I'm working on a Unicode version of TIPA, with lots of additional glyphs & diacritics. I need to define OT features governing diacritic placement, but for practical purposes it's hard to define all 180 x 180 pairs. I'm looking for ideas which pairs to definitely include (on top of those already present in the Unicode standard in the form of pre-composed characters, such as "a circumflex acute"), and for pairs placed in the same position, e.g. both at the bottom, or both at the top.

I additionally have a problem with long descender glyphs, as used in transcription, with bottom diacritics. The IPA only gives the example of "eng" + "combining ring below". Are there other instances I should provide for? What's the best practice in situations when moving a diacritic from the bottom to the top position would change the meaning of that diacritic, e.g. retracted vs. mid (tone, level), voiced vs. rising (tone, contour)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One thing you might do is study the Brill font (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485523) for how it approaches the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although an interesting question, it's not about TeX and therefore off-topic on this site.

Comment: Re Thérèse: Thank you :)

Comment: Re chsk: While that's true, it's hard to find guidelines for that sort of thing, and: 1. people who need to stack diacritics favour TeX over other systems, 2. the font I'm working on is a version of TIPA. Where else am I likely to find a community familiar with the problem?

Comment: Re Thérèse: Wow, thank you again, it's an amazing resource and will help me greatly.