# Bad quality IPA Symbols

Tags: symbols, tipa, phonetic

I am trying to insert some IPA symbols using the TIPA package. The quality of these symbols seem to be lower than the other characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\textfishhookr\textschwa\textepsilon ea

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the log output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.1.12)  15 JAN 2019 10:18
entering extended mode
**./simple.tex
(simple.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\tipa.sty"
Package: tipa 2002/08/08 TIPA version 1.1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.def"
File: ot1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OT1 on input line 48.
))) (simple.aux)
\openout1 = `simple.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 4.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd"
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 [1

{C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (simple.aux
) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1239 strings out of 493312
 14138 string characters out of 3138899
 58197 words of memory out of 3000000
 4853 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5408 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,4n,23p,139b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\tipa\dpi600
\tipa10.pk><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pf
b>
Output written on simple.pdf (1 page, 11865 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Is there a way to improve it?

EDIT: I solved the problem by switching the compiler to xelatex. In TexStudio, Option->Configure->Build->Default Compiler->xelatex

Comment: Could you add a compilable MWE?

Comment: In my case, the quality of the letters are good.

Comment: Can it be that I am missing some fonts?

Comment: Could you post the log from compiling this MWE?

Comment: @user2148564 [What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abU4V.png). The quality is not very good because of a screenshot. I see that the qualities of the letters are equally good.

Comment: Compiling the code you added I also get good-quality symbols.  This is with TeX live 2015 (I thought I was running a newer version than this, but apparently not).  Searching here for *raster fonts* might help; [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically) may be particularly useful but I can't test as I can't duplicate

Comment: In my test, using TeXLive 2018, I can see I use PFB versions of both TIPA and CMR. So you are probably missing fonts in your MikTeX installation. I don't use miktex, so no idea how you get the right out line font for TIPA. The CM versions should be fixed by installing cm-super, which is the default in TeXLive, but not in MikTeX.

Comment: I installed the cm-super package. The result is the same. Now I am getting this warning: 

Font shape `T3/aer/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead(Font) for symbol `textfishhookr'

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` not sure if it helps. Btw use @name to ping the person you're replying to. Otherwise they might not notice you added a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, your installation is not using the Type1 fonts that come with `tipa` and is falling back to bitmapped fonts instead.  I can’t reproduce this bug on my system.  You might try to reinstall `tipa`.

Consider switching to the modern toolchain, with either XeTeX or LuaTeX.  If you [can use the methods here to insert IPA characters as Unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249260/61644), or a character map, or copy and paste from a chart, you can just omit `tipa` entirely:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = TeX]

\begin{document}
ɾəɛea
\end{document}
```

[image: Charis SIL font sample]

You could also declare

```
\newcommand\textfishhookr{ɾ}
\newcommand\textschwa{ə}
\newcommand\textepsilon{ɛ}
```

Life is simpler if you just pick a main font that contains IPA symbols. It is possible to select a different one only for them (`ucharclasses` might help), or to use `tipa` and `fontspec` together, in which case you’ll fall back to the legacy `tipa` fonts as needed.  (This will have the disadvantage that copying-and-pasting from the PDF will not work, as it does with Unicode.)

If you’re stuck working with PDFLaTeX, I’d recommend as a best practice that you update to something like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[tone,extra,safe]{tipa}

\begin{document}
\textfishhookr\textschwa\textepsilon ea
\end{document}
```