# Problems Inserting Arabic Transcripts

Tags: arabic, tipa

I have been having difficulty inserting my Arabic transcripts and translations into my paper written in English.  In order to typeset the Arabic I have been using polyglossia; however, in my paper, I have also used tipa for IPA symbols.  Since tipa requires utf8 and polyglossia is not compatible with utf8, the two are incompatible, and I have not found a way to compile them together.

I am willing to change both or either package; I just need to be able to compile the document together.

Any help is appreciated.

The Arabic works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tipa} %IPA
%\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
الجملة مثال   
\end{Arabic} \\

\begin{english} 
al-\textipa{Z}umla mi\textipa{T}aal
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

The IPA works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa} %IPA
\usepackage{utf8}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
الجملة مثال   
\end{Arabic} \\

\begin{english} 
al-\textipa{Z}umla mi\textipa{T}aal
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64830 ?

Comment: I just tried.  Sadly, it still told me that it was unable to work with utf8 based engines.

Comment: We need a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order to help you.

Comment: I very reluctantly gave up on `tipa` and ASCII-only input for IPA symbols as a relic of the past. Besides `al-\textipa{Z}umla` is not the most elegant input. Is there any reason why yoou don't just use the unicode symbols directly? `al-ʒumla`. Use CMU Serif as the English font

Comment: @Au101 Thank you!  I finally got it to work!  I was unaware that certain fonts were already unicode enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For those being bound to ascii input by strong and lasting ties as I am, here is a solution without `polyglossia`.  It needs `lualatex` and is compatible with `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}

\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

UTF Arabic input:
\begin{txarab}
الجملة مثال   
\end{txarab}

arabtex ASCII input:
\begin{arab}
  al-jumlaT mi_tAl
\end{arab}

TIPA:\\
al-\textipa{Z}umla mi\textipa{T}aal

\end{document}
```